# Django Setting Custom Path for Storage ('str object is not callable')

Tags: python, django

I have a custom storage class I'm using and I am trying to set a different path to upload the file to but I keep getting "Str object is not callable".

Here's the code where I call my custom class:

```
fs = DGStorage(user_login=user_login, name=name, content=content, csv=True)
fs.path = os.path.join("/u/vnc/web", "docs", "upload", "csv")
```

When fs.save is called, I get the str object error (very annoying). I don't set the path in the storage class because it's set somewher else.

Custom Storage Model:

```
class DGStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def __init__(self, name=None, content=None, user_login=None, location=None, base_url=None,
                 file_permissions_mode=None, directory_permissions_mode=None, csv=False):
        # FileSystemStorage.__init__(self, self.location)
        self._location = location
        self._base_url = base_url
        self._file_permissions_mode = file_permissions_mode
        self._directory_permissions_mode = directory_permissions_mode
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
        self.user_login = str(user_login)
        self.user_dir = self.user_login + datetime.now().strftime('_%Y%m%d')
        self.csv = csv
        super(DGStorage, self).__init__()

@property
def user_directory(self):
    return safe_join(self.location, 'uploads', self.user_dir)

@property
def get_filename(self):
    if not self.name:
        self.name = self.content.name

    name = self.name
    name = name.replace(' ', '_')

    return name

def path(self, name=None):

    if not name:
        name = self.content.name
    else:
        name = name.replace(' ', '_')

    #if self.csv:
    #    return os.path.join("/u/vnc/web", "docs", "upload", "csv")
    return safe_join(self.location, 'uploads', self.user_dir, name)
```

The self.csv doesn't seem to work either, it just halts when I set the path that way as well.

Comment: Can you share the `DGStorage` model? I have the idea that you specified a wrong `default`.

Comment: I have added it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Used an if statement in the path. Wasn't passing in the file name.

Silly of me.